# How can I fix the issue with illegal characters (for Windows directory names) in a github remote repository with access to Linux?

Tags: git, github, repository

I created a github repository and uploaded several directories and files to it from an office PC which runs Linux. I tried to clone this repository onto my Windows laptop at home but it won't let me because some of the repositories have colons in the name which seem to be illegal directory name characters in Windows.

I will not have access to the Linux office PC for a few days. So I am unable to edit the original directory names and replace the colons with legal characters.

But I need to do work with this repository now on my Windows laptop, so is there anyway to fix this issue without access to a Linux machine? Is it possible to somehow rename these directories on github, or rename them through ssh on Windows? It surely seems possible if you have ssh credentials you should be able to edit remote directory names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rename these directories using the web interface, check [here](https://github.com/blog/1436-moving-and-renaming-files-on-github)
[image]

Comment: That seems to just be for files, not directories?

Comment: If there are only a few files, you can use this to move them to a valid directory.@eurocoder

Comment: Unfortunately there are too many files for this to be an option.

Comment: Maybe you can find another Linux machine(create a virtual machine for example), and then download the files from github, then copy to the host machine.